# Problems running XBAP apps more than once

Tags: silverlight, xbap

I'm trying to run a XBAP application from behind a proxy server, the first time I load it it works fine. The second time I get a generic "WPF Host has failed" Error message. The xbap file itself downloads correctly, it just fails to execute.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is related to Silverlight how?

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have tagged it silverlight, but did so as they are both very similar alternatives to one another and was hoping that someone with silverlight experience might also have come across this fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved. Caused by a ssl cert intercepting corp proxy that was rewriting the certificate which meant the application no longer trusted it.